# variable plus 1 after each time running the script

Tags: linux, shell, loops

```
for file in `ls |grep '\..$'`
do
num=0
while [ $num -lt 100 ]
num=`expr $num + 1`
sed -i "_bak" "s/\/\/.*version.*/\/\/calcmarks, version $num ,released `date "+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"`/" "$file"
done
```

what I want is to let the variable each time I run this script , the variable plus 1.
For example, original textile is

//calcmarks, version 1 ,released Thu Apr 06 20:50:54 AWST 2017

After I run the script ,I hope it become

//calcmarks, version 2 ,released xxxxxxxxxxxxx

and then

//calcmarks, version 3 ,released xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

So I set a variable $num

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: `for file in $(ls |grep '.c$')` -- that's crazy! `for file in *.c; do ...`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to place `num=0` before the loop instead of in it?

Comment: `ls` is just plain unnecessary here. It's an external command whose output is intended specifically to be read by a human, not parsed by a script. Avoid using while programming in bash, specially for loops.

Comment: @Jens @Ashish K okay, I learned it from you now.  I haven't touched this area for long time. And it  works actually using for ... in `ls`,so I think it's right.

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's right.  I could drive from my house in San Francisco to New York City and back just to get the kids to school, but that doesn't make it a good idea.  The point is that you can simply use `for file in *.c` as Jens mentioned to accomplish the same task faster and more efficiently.  It also means that the next person to come along won't have to waste time trying to figure out why you used `ls | grep ...` instead of using `*.c`.

Comment: Beyond the `ls` issue, either this code won't do what you want or you've not stated your problem well enough for anyone to help.  What this is doing (syntactical errors aside) is: _for each file in  a directory, change the version number 100 times so that it ends up as 100 with the current date._  I suspect that what you really want to do is read each file, find the appropriate "calcmarks" record, and add one to the current version.   Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see, how this question is related to the code you are posting (where you increment a variable within a loop), but when you want to store a state (here: the version number) between script invocations, you need to store the value in a file.

Create a file `$HOME/version`, and store the version number in the file. On each invocation, read the content of the file, increment the variable, and write it back to the file.

While this is trivial, there is one tricky aspect contained: If you run two instances of your script in parallel, you have a race condition about updating the version number. To be on the safe side, you should consider file locking.